# Google app engine-php: script handler

Tags: php, google-app-engine, handler

I try to create php web app using GAE.

In the GAE tutorial, "A script handler executes a PHP script to handle the request that matches the URL pattern. The mapping defines a URL pattern to match, and the script to be executed"

Now I want to map the url with the file having same name in the folder, e.g. if the url is /hello.* ,  it will map the file name hello.php in the folder. And if it is /hello1.*, hello1.php in the folder will be responded to the server.

I thought this should be done directly by mapping the name of the url with the name in the folder. But if I left empty for the handler in the app.yaml, I got an error.

So I want to know how to set up the handler in app.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the digit character class to extract digits, use ? for matching 0 or more times, use .* to match the rest of the url.

```
- url: /hello(\d?).*
  script: hello\1.php
```

Of course if you just want to match an incoming URL to a file of the same name you can use

```
- url: /(.*)\.php$
  script: (\1).php
```

If you don't want them to specify the .php a the end of the URL then it's

```
- url : /(.*)
  script: (\1).php
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain what does `(\1)` means? @Stuart Langley

Comment: Read up on regex capture groups. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers

```
handlers:
- url: /hello([0-9]*).(.*)
  script: /hello\1.php
```

I think you would do something similar to that.  The odds are good that the RegEx is incorrect, but you get the idea.